# PHP preg_match_all - regex and breakline

Tags: php, regex, curl

Here's me function with regexp:

```
preg_match_all('|<span class=\"Menu1\">(.*?)</td>|U',$contents,$wynik2);
```

It works with:

```
  <tr>
        <td width="30%" ><span class="Menu"> Nazwa zawdsdu: </td>
        <td width="70%"> <span class="Menu1">PRACOWNIK BARU  </td>
        </tr>
```

but it doesn't work with:

```
<td width="70%"> <span class="Menu1">PRACA W MC DONALDS PRACE PORZĄDKOWE, PRZYJĘCIE DOSTAWY
WYMAGANA KSIĄŻECZKA SANEPIDOWSKA, CHĘCI DO PRACY
KONTAKT TEL. 794295401 </td>
```

I've got empty array.
I think its caused by 'new line'. How can i fix it?

Comment: Only broken things need fixes. However, that is the intended behaviour. Start with reading about regular expressions, especially what the `.` (Dot) character stands for: [PCRE regex syntax: Dot (PHP Manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I felt obliged to give a DOMDocument example:

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);

foreach ($xpath->query('//span[@class="Menu1"]') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Applied to your scraper (redacted the url and post fields)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://redacted');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'redacted');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$d = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$d->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);

foreach ($xpath->query('//span[@class="Menu1"]') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: It works, but i cannot see polish letter ie. Ę and Ą. HTML come from CURL and is <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">

Comment: Ok, I've done this:
 preg_match_all('@<span class="Menu1">(.*?)</tr>@si', $contents, $wynik2);

Comment: @ArturStary If you're using iso-8859-2 you should of course change the meta header; do you have a URL perhaps?

Comment: I'm scrapping that website http://goo.gl/ubMjL and click "szczegoly" (otherwise you need to send data via POST to get there)

Comment: @ArturStary I've updated my answer, it should work fine now; didn't need the utf-8 header :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `s` modifier to the end of your regex.